# dictionary app development

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I was wondering if anyone has ever created a simple dictionary app? Not NSDictionary, but an app like a thesaurus/dictionary. I'm having problems figuring out how to make my text field read in a word, and then having it search at all.

Did you use a simple array? An excel sheet? Thanks!

Comment: An Excel sheet in an iOS app?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on amount of data you want to keep.

CoreData (SQLLite) sounds most reasonable especially if you think about searching speed for user input and ease of showing data in table view.

Answer (score 1):

The first question should be whether you want to a) search online for results (e.g. on your webserver, or using a public API of a commercial partner) or b) store data (i.e. your dictionary) on the device.

The typical (not necessarily the best for your case) way to proceed is to use a `UITableViewController` and add a search bar for entering the query. If you are going for a) you have to call your API and b) could be done using a `NSFetchRequest` with some `NSPredicate` if your are using CoreData.